# Read from a input file until a string appears in C++

Tags: c++, string, file, inputstream, ifstream

I have an input file (`.txt`) like below -

```
BEGIN
ABC
DEF
END
BEGIN
XYZ
RST
END
```

I have to extract everything from BEGIN to END and store them in a string. So, from this file I'll have two strings.

```
"ABC
DEF"

"XYZ
RST"
```

I am using `ifstream` to read the input file. My question is, how can I parse the input file to get everything from one BEGIN to next END. `getline()` has character as delimiter, not string. Another way I tried was copying everything from the input file to a string and then parse the string based on `.find()`. However, in this method, I only get the first BEGIN to END.

Is there any way I can store everything in a string from the input file until a certain string appears (END)?

For storing purpose, I am using a `vector<string>` to store.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Replace filename with a proper name.

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    char filename[] = "a.txt";
    std::vector<string> v;
    std::ifstream input(filename);
    string temp = "";
    for(std::string line; getline( input, line ); )
    {
        if(string(line) == "BEGIN")
            continue;
        else if(string(line) == "END")
        {
            v.push_back(temp);
            temp = "";
        }
        else
        {
            temp += string(line);
        }

    }
    for(int i=0; i<v.size(); i++)
        cout<<v[i]<<endl;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
bool start = false;
vector<string> v;

while (...)
{
  string line = ifs.getline();
  if (line == "START")
  {
    start = true;
    continue;
  }
  if (line == "END")
  {
    start = false;
    process(v);
    v.clear();
    continue;
  }
  if (start)
    v.push_back(line);
}
```

Comment: Is process(v) a windows function? I am running on linux using g++. It says process was not declared in this scope. I am not sure if thats the case.

Comment: @user3503711 this function is called when a BEGIN-END run was found, it is up to you how you will implement it. For example: `void process(vector<string>& arrayOfStrings) { for (const auto& l : arrayOfStrings) cout << l << endl; }`